# WPF ListBox always previous item selected on each change of selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, enums, listbox

I am facing strange problem regarding WPF ListBox. I have tried all variations of setting ListBox bindings, but it still the same.

As soon as I change the selection and click on different item other than which is already selected, It jumps back to the previous selected item. On second click , it get selected afterwards which is completely wrong. 
I debugged and see that everything is al right. After calling RaisePropertyChange(Property), it jumps to the getter section of property and everything fine there too. It is returning the valid value from there.

But after returning and before displaying again selected value, something bad happens and due to that, it jumps back to the previously selected item ( anchorItem ).

Following is the XAML for this.

```
<ListBox x:Name="yGradesListBox"   
              Style="{StaticResource enumListBox}"
              SectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedYieldGrade}"/>
```

While The binding Property is :

```
public YieldGrade SelectedYieldGrade
        {
            get
            {                       
                if (_sides[0].YieldGradeState == SelectionState.Selected)
                    return YieldGradeConverter.Convert(_sides[0].YieldGrade);
                if (_sides[1].YieldGradeState == SelectionState.Selected)
                    return YieldGradeConverter.Convert(_sides[1].YieldGrade);

 //this is the condition that meets after RaisePropertyChange and it has to be returned.
                   if (this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade != YieldGrade.NoGrade)                    
                    return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;

                return YieldGrade.NoGrade;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade == YieldGrade.NoGrade || this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade != value)
                {
                    this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade = value;
                    foreach (SideViewModel sideData in _sides.Where(sideData => sideData.HasData))
                    {
                        sideData.YieldGradeState = SelectionState.Overwritten;
                    }
                    this.CarcassDto.YieldGradeOverrideState = this.GetYieldGradeOverride();
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedYieldGrade");

                    _model.OnCarcassDataChanged(this, new CarcassDataChangedEventArgs() { RecalcProgram = true });
                }
            }
        }
```

and YieldGrade type is Enum defined in the code

```
public enum YieldGrade
{
    [Description("No Grade")]
    NoGrade = 0,
    [Description("Y1")]
    YG1 = 1,
    [Description("Y2")]
    YG2 = 2,
    [Description("Y3")]
    YG3 = 3,
    [Description("Y4")]
    YG4 = 4,
    [Description("Y5")]
    YG5 = 5
}
```

Now If I click on any item represented by above enum, the selection would be jumped back to the anchor value( i.e the previously selected ).
I ahve applied all combinitions of properties in markup ( e.g TwoWay, SelectedItem )

Please help me out to solve this , I would be extremly obliged. I am kind a stuck here.

Regards
Usman

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much with get set
**The get should return the set**

If this is your set

```
this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade = value;
```

Then this should be your get

```
return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;
```

And you should not modify this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade in the get

This is just squirrely

```
if (this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade != YieldGrade.NoGrade)                    
   return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;
   return YieldGrade.NoGrade;
```

Same as

```
if (this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade == YieldGrade.NoGrade)
{
    return YieldGrade.NoGrade;
}
else 
{                    
    return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;
}
```

Same as

```
if (this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade == YieldGrade.NoGrade)
{
    return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;
}
else 
{                    
    return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;
}
```

Same as

```
return this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;
```

Comment: No sir, this does not make any differnce to my problem. I want to return USDAYieldGrade if it does not match the specified condition and other wise it shoudl return NoGrade.

That's not the issue concerning to my problem

Comment: But if it does not match that condition then they are equal and it is the same as returning this.CarcassDto.USDAYieldGrade;

Comment: And you missed my answer - The get should return the set